# MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR when acessing kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am fairly new to Kubernetes. up until a month ago, I was able to access the kubernetes dashboard but for some reason one day I encountered a problem: when pressing the "sign in" button after uploading the config file, nothing happens.
i went into developer tools in chrome and saw the next error message in "config":

```
{
 "status": 401,
 "plugins": [],
 "errors": [
  {
   "ErrStatus": {
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR",
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

also, in the CMD window where i run `kubectl proxy`, the line:
`2020/10/20 15:33:54 http: proxy error: context canceled`
keeps showing everytime I press the button.
i've checked that my proxy is configured correctly, and my peers are able to access the dashboard service. the version is 1.16 and it is connected from localhost:8001.
I've read and tried almost any thread out there but nothing seems to work: disabling security in chrome, reconfiguring the proxy, etc.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does your kubectl client version match k8s server version? (run `kubectl version` to check it)

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18"
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16" seems like it's not the same version. is it possible to update the k8s server version ?

Comment: Dont update the server, downgrade the client and check if it works: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#client-binaries-22